# Как создать консольное приложение .Net Standard?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

> Внимание! Это перевод вопроса [Console App (.Net Standard) not
>   listed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45788018/5752652)

Я использую Visual Studio 2017 и пытаюсь создать проект "Console App (.Net Standard)".  Однако его нет в в списке возможных проектов, когда я выбираю "File -> New Project..."

[image: options in Visual Studio]

Как же мне это можно сделать?

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/q/45788018/5752652

Answer (score 6):

Никак.

Этого сделать не получится никаким способом. Консольных проектов на .Net Standard не существует в природе.

Вы можете выбрать консольное приложение на .Net Framework или на .Net Core - но проекты .Net Standard могут быть библиотеками, которые можно подключить либо в консольное приложение .Net Framework, либо в консольное приложение .Net Core.

Можете думать о .NET Standard по аналогии с интерфейсами C#: .NET Standard — это как интерфейс, он не имеет конкретной реализации. Он может быть реализован либо в приложении .NET Framework, приложении .NET Core и других платформах.

Проект .NET Standard имеет смысл только как библиотека классов, а не как консольное приложение.